# Getting IndexError when index increases to greater than 50

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to take each line from an existing .txt file of partial URLs (one per line), strip %0A from the end of each line, add a prefix to each URL to complete it, then download the HTML file for each completed URL to my hard drive for scraping later/in a next step using BeautifulSoup.

The code below works pretty well, except for two issues:

1) Each downloaded HTML file has all HTML data properly available off-line (when View Source on the file), but when opened in Firefox does not contain any visible data except page headers/banners, and

2) Script throws an **"oidstripped[j] = str(offenderid[j]) IndexError: list assignment index out of range"** at j=51 each time it is run. It correctly downloads files for j=1 through 50, but then crashes and will not continue.

```
#snip#
j = 0
with open('offenderurls.txt') as r:
    offenderid = r.readlines()
    while j < len(offenderid):
       oidstripped = []
        for l in offenderid[j]:
          oidstripped.append(l)
       oidstripped[j] = str(offenderid[j])
       oidstripped[j] = oidstripped[j][:-1]
       res = requests.get('http://www.icrimewatch.net/' +  str(oidstripped[j]), stream=True)
       type(res)
       res.raise_for_status()
       with open('Offenderpage' + str(j) + '.html', 'wb') as playFile:
            for chunk in res.iter_content(1024):
                playFile.write(chunk)
            playFile.close()
    j = j + 1
```

Please help! I am very new to python. No need to be gentle. Thick skin. All advice will be considered and appreciated.

Example offenderurls.txt with 55 entries is here: https://pastebin.ca/3886683

Thanks!

Comment: You can try using a loop like this: `f = open('somefile.txt','r')
for line in f.readlines():
    ...
    //do something with each line
    ....

f.close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you goal correctly, this should help.

You don't need the `oidstripped` at all, try following

```
for one_id in offenderid:
  res = requests.get('http://www.icrimewatch.net/' +  one_id.rstrip('\n'), stream=True)
```

Instead of while loop.

The rest I didn't test.